# Запрет посещать страницу если неактивна сессия

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Знакомлюсь с ASP.NET webforms, вопрос, правильно ли я сделал, если сессия неактивна и при попытке перейти на какую то страницу без авторизации на всех страницах у меня стоит

```
if (Session["ID_USER"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

Переадресация на страницу входа.

Comment: Возможны варианты. 1. В том же user есть свойство `Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` (в одном из проэктов, авторизация Forms). 2. Можно настроить через web.config (у меня так настроено). А ваш вариант похож на "ручной"

Comment: сессия и аутентификация - две совершенно разные вещи в asp.net. сессия - это текущая браузерная сессия, она никакого отношения к логину и авторизации не имеет. вам нужна именно аутентификация. Посмотрите https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7t6b43z4.aspx и дальше по ссылкам.

Comment: Мне показалось по ID_USER что вы пытаетесь сделать "ручную" авторизацию. Часто авторизация привязывается к сессии (при пропаже сессии пропадает авторизация), но не всегда.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Проще всего - настройте web.config так:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

И не нужно тогда делать кучу проверок.

Вариант 2. проверяйте свойство `Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Возможно есть ещё другие варианты проверки, привёл то что по-проще.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали в 1 варианте, страница логина и дефолта у меня это одна и та же страница. Сделал так :     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/index.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="index.aspx" protection="All" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
    </authentication>.  При попытке пройти на другие страницы без авторизации все ок проходит - то есть не пашет.

Comment: @Winteriscoming Добавьте за authentication  конфиг `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>`.